# AWS Lambda: async C# handler

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The AWS document states that

> Using Async in C# Functions with AWS Lambda
>
> If you know your Lambda function will require a long-running process,
>   such as uploading large files to Amazon S3 or reading a large stream
>   of records from DynamoDB, you can take advantage of the async/await
>   pattern. By creating a handler with this signature, Lambda will
>   execute the function synchronously and wait a maximum of 5 minutes for
>   execution to complete before returning or timing out.

I feel very confused Lambda will

> execute the function **synchronously and wait a maximum of 5 minutes**

When Lambda support up to 15 minutes of processing time.
Does that mean if I put async on the handler, I can only process one event in 5 minutes?

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks. I removed the broad part and would ask the AWS support instead. I do have some basic understanding about async in .NET and used both async/non async in Lambda integration. 
I will create an answer if I can get a definitive one from AWS support

Comment: This to me was an interesting question I have a feeling the documentation has not been updated and should read: "By creating a handler with this signature, Lambda will execute the function synchronously and wait a maximum of 15 minutes for execution to complete before returning or timing out."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The final answer of AWS support at the time:

- The document was not up to date. It should run at maximum 15 minute timeout ( depend on the Lambda function configuration )
- The async modifier does not change how AWS behave, they will just await it.
- The behaviour diference is only on the .NET side

Comment: "The behaviour diference is only on the .NET side"
What does this mean?

Comment: The support meant that the difference is that of an await-ed async .NET function vs synchronous invocation. AWS do not do anything notable with it

Answer (score 0):

AWS recently changed the timeout for Lamdba. The execution timeout is changed from 5 minutes to 15 minutes.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/